# XHR cross-domain error on the same domain (localhost)

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

## Explanation:

I have a small web application running on apache server on a machine that uses javascript to do some XHR's. For a long time it worked with no problems, today all the XHR's stopped working but only on localhost, if you access it from outside it works perfectly.

## Problem:

Using mozilla firefox, firebug warns:

> > "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at `http://127.0.0.1:3581/datasnap/rest/TdssMloteamento/getLoteamento/true/`. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

But i'm on localhost acessing a local content that have XHR calls a local datasnap server on the same machine, resuming, locally it fails, and from web it works.

## Comments:

I am acessing apache web page within url: `http://127.0.0.1:3582/beeWebLoteamento/Principal.php`

This is totally, really, **weird** for me, that just does not make sense, no-logic, why i get a cross-domain error if i'm acessing the same domain?

## Objective:

I want to know what is happening and solve this problem to continue doing my XHR's locally and via the web (external) too.

Comment: What does the URL look like for the requesting page? The protocol ("http" or "https"), the hostname, and the port must be **exactly** the same.

Comment: This is a normal XHR request on a delphi datasnap server, i send a json and i get a json returned.

Comment: Right. So does the requesting page URL start with `http://localhost:3581`?

Comment: Starts with `http://127.0.0.1:3581`

Comment: how can you run apache and "datasnap server on the same machine"? they would have to use different ports, and ports are an included part of domain enforcement. also, localhost is a different domain than 127.0.0.1, as fas as JS is concerned.

Comment: Yes, i use port 3582 to apache and 3581 to datasnap

Comment: @PauloRoberto: well those are different servers now, aren't they? (ports count)

Comment: Nope. they are on the same server, but listening on different ports, i accessed them using the local ip adrress of the machine `192.168.25.100` instead of using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` and it worked fine, see details at my answer.

Comment: Just FYI the "origin" includes the protocol, domain, **and** port. So even if you're trying to make a request between two endpoints with the same protocol and domain, if the ports are different then it will be treated as a CORS request.

Comment: I think that you're wrong, because it worked now and i'm from a web page in 3582 port doing a XHR to 3581 port and it now worked.

Comment: Nope, [I am correct](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-abarth-origin-09#section-4). "…the two origins are the same if, and only if, they have identical schemes, hosts, and ports."

Comment: The browser compares the hostname as a **string** - it doesn't matter that "localhost" resolves to the same IP address.  The strings must be identical. The port numbers have to be exactly the same too.

Answer (score 2):

## I found the solution/problem, that is:

Replaced all `127.0.0.1` to `192.168.25.100`(that is the local machine ip) and everything worked fine, so the request was:

> `http://127.0.0.1:3581/datasnap/rest/TdssMloteamento/getLoteamento/true/`

and became:

> `http://192.168.25.100:3581/datasnap/rest/TdssMloteamento/getLoteamento/true/`

And i acessed my web application (apache) within the URL:

> `http://192.168.25.100:3582/beeWebLoteamento/Principal.php`

## Resuming:

To avoid these cross-domain problems, use the local ip address of the machine "that usually starts with `192.168.xxx.xxx`" to access everything that are hosted on it, nor XHR either Apache, instead of using `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`

Comment: This will only work if the application accessed via XHR is sending back an appropriate access control header (which in this case is quite likely). Normally, the port number is part of the "same domain" rule.

Comment: well, this only worked because my datasnap server send a access control in the header?

Comment: I think so, yes - you can verify what's going on by looking at the "Network" tab in your browser developer tools. You should be able to see all the response headers sent back.

Answer (score 0):

try send header `access-control-allow-origin: *`  in your backend script