# XHR to same domain being blocked

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm having a pretty weird problem with CORS on a webapp I'm trying to make
I'm using Servlets (Tomcat8.0) for the backend. It's a school project, so I can't use a framework

A GET request to `http://localhost:8080/FileBox/dashboard`
returns a JSON payload( plain json, not jsonp,which I could use, but its the same domain). I'm using ajax to make the XHR, but it's being blocked by chrome as CORS[image: XHR blocked by chrome]

Should this be happening, since I'm making the XHR from the same domain(host+port)
`'localhost:8080/FileBox/dashboard.jsp' 
to 
'localhost:8080/FileBox/dashboard'`

Please, and thank you for the help!

Comment: I've looked at these, but they weren't particularly helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966707/cors-error-on-same-domain?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772001/xhr-cross-domain-error-on-the-same-domain-localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't making a request to `http://localhost:8080/FileBox/dashboard`. The error message says you are making a cross-origin request using an unsupported scheme and that `http` is a supported scheme.

Presumably you have made the two mistakes of:

## Getting the URL wrong

You should be using a relative URL:

```
/FileBox/dashboard
```

but are trying to use an absolute URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/FileBox/dashboard
```

but have typed it wrong and are actually requesting

```
localhost:8080/FileBox/dashboard
```

## Not loading the page over HTTP to start with

Possibly by double clicking the file in your system file manager, you have bypassed your HTTP server and are loading something like `file:///c:/users/you/yourproject/index.html`

---

Combined with the previous mistake, you end up trying to request `file:///c:/users/you/yourproject/localhost:8080/FileBox/dashboard`, with Ajax and get a security violation.

---

## Solution

1. Fix the URL to be a proper relative URL
2. Point your browser at `http://localhost:8080` instead of double clicking files in your file manager

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'm running a server, so It's not the second issue, I'll try and see If I can use a relative url

Comment: @DancesOnTheMoon — The second issue is that you appear to be running a server but aren't telling the browser to talk to it.

Comment: It was the first issue, I was using an absolute url. I'm not aware why this should be a problem, since it's the same domain, but your answer helped me. Thanks